# binded variable giving undefined error javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(a("`${data[0].p}`", [ { p:0 } ]))

function a (string, data) {

    return eval.bind(data)(string)
}
```

`ReferenceError: data is not defined` I'm pretty sure I binded `data` to `eval`, however for some reason it gives me an error saying `data` is not defined. The error came from:

```js
`${data[0].p}`
^
```

Comment: @Teemu what do you mean?

Comment: @Teemu isn't the eval function inside the `data` scope?

Comment: Are you after just `eval(string)`? As eval will use the scope of the function its being called it, it will have access to `data` (although I wouldn't suggest using `eval()` for this task). `eval.bind(...)(...)` results in an indirect eval call, so the code runs in the global scope outside your function, where `data` doesn't exist.